# How can I restart mongodb quickly after an unexpected shutdown

Tags: mongodb

My mongodb(version v3.2.8) runs with journal=true option, but after an unexpected shutdown, it takes a very very long time to restart(70GB database size).
I have try the repair option, but it's no use.

So how can I restart mongodb quickly.

Any help will be great.Thanks !

Here's my conf:

```
dbpath=/data/mongodb/new_db
logpath=/data/mongodb/logs/mongodb.log
fork=true
httpinterface=true
rest=true
journal=true
wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=3
```

mongodb start log:

```
2016-10-25T15:36:53.442+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.8
2016-10-25T15:36:53.442+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ed70e33130c977bda0024c125b56d159573dbaf0
2016-10-25T15:36:53.442+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-10-25T15:36:53.442+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-10-25T15:36:53.442+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-10-25T15:36:53.442+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-10-25T15:36:53.442+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-10-25T15:36:53.442+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/usr/local/mongodb/conf/mongodb.conf", net: { http: { RESTInterfaceEnabled: true, enabled: true } }, processManagement: { fork: true }, storage: { dbPath: "/data/mongodb/new_db", journal: { enabled: true }, wiredTiger: { engineConfig: { cacheSizeGB: 3 } } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "/data/mongodb/logs/mongodb.log" } }
2016-10-25T15:36:53.457+0800 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/mongodb/new_db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2016-10-25T15:36:53.457+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
```

Comment: The log entries, judging by the timestamps, are all logged within a fraction of a second. Is there more to the log, showing what it is doing when it takes a long time?

Comment: @VinceBowdren That's all the log. So I think mongodb is blocked by some    operation

Comment: How long does it actually take to restart - and does the log really say nothing more when it has finished restarting?

Comment: Yes, the log say nothing more. Actually, I waited for several hours, but mongodb hasn't finished restarting yet, and it consumed CPU all the time.